# javascript: differentiate keys in array maps

Tags: javascript, dictionary, maps, key

I wrote a little script to transliterate from Latin to a different script. Some characters are transliterated in Latin with two letters. For example (see code) g and j become `gj` (`\u{1050B}`). However, the script does not output `gj` when "gj" is entered, but `g` and `j` (`\u{1050A}` and `\u{1050E}`) separately. How can I distinguish the keys from each other?

```js
function transliterate(word){
  var l = {
    /*...*/'g':'\u{1050A}','gj':'\u{1050B}','h':'\u{1050C}','i':'\u{1050D}','j':'\u{1050E}'/*...*/
  };
  return word.split('').map(function (char) { 
    return l[char] || char; 
  }).join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First put the keys with multiple characters first, then use a regular expression to match any of the keys, starting with the first, instead of splitting by `''`.

```js
function transliterate(word) {
    const charCodes = {
      gj: '\u{1050B}',
      g: '\u{1050A}',
      h: '\u{1050C}',
      i: '\u{1050D}',
      j: '\u{1050E}'
    };
    const pattern = new RegExp(
      Object.keys(charCodes).join('|'),
      'g'
    );
    return word.replace(pattern, match => charCodes[match]);
  }
  console.log(transliterate('gjj'));
```

Comment: thank you! But I don't quite understand how I can do this for more keys. I also have keys like `gh` or `ngj`.

Comment: Just make sure the longer keys come first in the object, and you should be fine. Eg length 3 keys should come before length 2 keys, etc. Or, if that's too cumbersome, you could also sort them programmatically in the JS